# mediawiki not searching the word wonder?

Tags: search, mediawiki

i have a page with the word wonder in the title (in the namespace mainpage), and another file, that has in his text the wonder word, yet they arent found by the search engine (default one), why would this be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default search engine sucks rather hard :)

If it's not sufficient for you, I suggest having a look at getting one of the extensions that make use of a fulltext search engine, see https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Fulltext_search_engines

Comment: yeah i did but they dont want that, its to much bother for them (i was trying to applie the sphix search)